# BigQuery - SELECT list expression references column user_pseudo_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to LEFT JOIN two queries which are grouping by user_id from two tables that look like this:

t1: number_of_user_sessions

| user_id |
| --- |
| john |
| john |
| brian |

t1: number_of_searches

| user_id |
| --- |
| john |
| brian |
| brian |
| brian |

with the query returning

| user_id | number_of_user_sessions | number_of_searches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 2 | 1 |
| brian | 1 | 3 |

```
SELECT user_id , COUNT( user_id ) as num_sessions FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as num_search FROM t2
ON t1.user_pseudo_id = t2.user_pseudo_id
GROUP BY user_id  ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC
```

but keep getting hit with a `SELECT list expression references column user_pseudo_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated` error. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
select user_id,num_sessions,num_search
from (
select user_id , count(*) num_sessions
from t1
group by user_id 
) t1
left join (
select user_id , count(*) num_search
from t2
group by user_id 
) t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a bit of a problem. I will enter the correct form of your code below.

```
SELECT t1.user_id,COUNT(t1.user_id) as num_sessions,temp.num_search
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as num_search FROM t2
GROUP BY user_id) temp
ON t1.user_id= temp.user_id
GROUP BY t1.user_id,temp.num_search
ORDER BY COUNT(t1.user_id) DESC
```

Comment: this returns a new error ```SELECT list expression references temp.num_search which is neither grouped nor aggregated a```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with aggregation and `union all`:

```
select user_id, sum(is_session) as num_sessions, sum(is_search) as num_searches
from ((select user_id, 1 as is_session, 0 as is_search
       from number_of_user_sessions
      ) union all
      (select user_id, 0, 1
       from number_of_searches
      )
     ) u
group by user_id;
```

Or equivalently as:

```
select user_id, countif(which = 'session') as num_sessions, 
       countif(which = 'search') as num_searches
from ((select user_id, 'session' as which
       from number_of_user_sessions
      ) union all
      (select user_id, 'search'
       from number_of_searches
      )
     ) u
group by user_id;
```